# Is $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ a differentiable function?

Tags: calculus

When we speak of differentiable function, do we mean $C^1$ function?

I know $C^1$ means continuously differentiable.

Is $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ a $C^1$ function or $C^2$ function? Its second derivative blow up at $x = 0$. Is it $C^1$?

Does Taylor series exist for $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$?

Comment: It is differentiable on $x>0$. It is not differentiable if you define it on $x \geq 0$ as differentiable means differentiable at every point and it fails to be differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Differentiable only means the derivative exists, not that it is continuous.

Comment: but its first derivative is continuous at 0. So x^3/2 is differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The domain of your function is $x\ge 0$ and the derivative $\frac 32\sqrt x$ is well defined in this domain.

Answer (score -1):

Assume $x>0$. Then
$$
f(x)=x^{3/2},\quad f'(x)=\frac32 \sqrt{x},\quad f''(x)=\frac3{4\sqrt{x}}.
$$ Observe that all these functions are continuous over $(0,\infty)$, that is $f$ is $C^1(0,\infty)$. In fact, $f$ is $C^\infty(0,\infty)$.

Comment: how about for all range in real number?

Comment: You can't take all numbers in the domain since $\sqrt{x}$ is not defined for $x<0$.